# Jmeter Not Able to send Cookies In Quotes " ", Netscape doesn't work

Tags: jmeter, setcookie, jmeter-5.0

I am having this strange problem where i need to send multiple cookies as part of my Jmeter Script HTTP request.

Following are my cookies which i get in my response:

Set-Cookie:

AWSALB=CookieValue

AWSALBCORS=CookieValue

Pega-RULES="CookieValue"

If I select Standard Mechanism in Cookie manager it identifies all cookies, but doesn't send Pega-RULES cookie in Quotes " " in the next request and the scripts fail.

If i select Netscape in Cookie Manager it identifies only Pega-RULES Cookie and sends the cookie in "" but Doesn't recognize AWS Cookies and doesn't send AWS Cookies in next cookies, again the script fails.

Please help me find a solution.

Many Thanks,

Suhail

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
CookieManager.check.cookies=false
```

so if there is a problem with any of your cookies - JMeter will not "discard" it and send it with the next request even if it's expired or domain doesn't match, etc.

To get more insight regarding what's going on with the cookies under the hood you can [enable debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging/) for the HTTP Cookie Manager by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file

Also be aware that you can always extract any cookie from the [Set-Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie) response header using i.e. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) and add them either to HTTP Header Manager or to the HTTP Cookie Manager as user-defined cookie

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control" level="debug" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Dmitri! Though i'm still searching for a solution. I did have already CookieManager.check.cookies=false in my user.properties file as well as jmeter.properties file though when i select netscape in cookie manager i can still see the following error for my AWS cookies:                                                                              2020-06-11 00:38:48,542 ERROR o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Unable to add the cookie
org.apache.http.cookie.MalformedCookieException: Invalid 'expires' attribute: Wed, 17 Jun 2020 19:08:48 GMT
 at org.apache.http.impl.cookie.Basi

Comment: this is the cookie i received: 2020-06-11 00:38:48,542 DEBUG o.a.j.p.h.c.HC4CookieHandler: Received Cookie: AWSALBCORS=HPCjGDxBIiztyfmN2rIYVqSqUXk4hsDslNv5Ehw6ruwY427uXooEoU3udJ5OjK0OS+Txk1SVYRbPwUntRKUUEDPYAdnUr8vjqOh7ssNLHKhetGHqJgccDJo1tcw9; Expires=Wed, 17 Jun 2020 19:08:48 GMT;